# Remove duplicate rows has the same datetime from List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, group-by

I have list with 2 parameter's (dynamic)

- DateTime OrderDate
- decimal TotalPrice

every list may have a same `datetime` and diffrent `price`

```
- DateTime -- Price
- 10/10/10 -- 100
- 11/11/11 -- 111
- 11/11/11 -- 100
- 10/10/10 -- 122
- etc
```

now i need to combine them. for i see only 1 datetime and 1 price

```
- DateTime -- Price
- 10/10/10 -- 222
- 11/11/11 -- 211
- etc
```

here the code

```
var data = db.CheckOut.Where(x => x.ISOrderComplete == true).OrderBy(c => c.Order.OrderDate).ToArray()
    .GroupBy(y => new { OrderDate = y.Order.OrderDate, TotalPrice = y.TotalPrice })
    .Select(a => new { OrderDate = a.Key.OrderDate, TotalPrice = a.Key.TotalPrice })
    .ToList();
```

I try to add the function the

```
var data = db.CheckOut.Where(x => x.ISOrderComplete == true).OrderBy(c => c.Order.OrderDate).ToArray()
    .GroupBy(y => new { OrderDate = y.Order.OrderDate, TotalPrice = y.TotalPrice })
    .Select(a => new { OrderDate = a.Key.OrderDate, TotalPrice = a.Sum(b => b.TotalPrice) })
    .ToList();
```

What i have to do?

> i dont need this sum in db. i need this sum to display statistic about incoms to company in charts so i need to sum each data for how much getting .

Comment: This looks like it would be difficult to maintain in the future. Why don't you make it look simpler and split it out?

Comment: Can you explain? An example?

Comment: Well instead of using a lambda expression. Just split it out. Grab the data, group it. sum up the `TotalPrice` and then add it into a list.

Comment: the problem is i dont know how to get the values to equels each other.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = db.CheckOut.Where(x => x.ISOrderComplete == true)
                .GroupBy(y => new { OrderDate = y.Order.OrderDate})
                .Select(a => new { OrderDate = a.Key.OrderDate, TotalPrice = a.Sum(b => b.TotalPrice)})
                .OrderBy(c => c.Order.OrderDate)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Following deramko approach, the only missing thing is that you shouldn't group by `OrderDate`, but instead, `OrderDate.Date`, because the time can be different.

Try something like this:

```
var data = db.CheckOut.Where(x => x.IsCheckoutComplete)
        .GroupBy(x => new { OrderDate = x.Order.OrderDate.Date})
        .Select(a => new { OrderDate = a.Key.OrderDate, TotalPrice = a.Sum(b => b.Order.TotalPrice)})
        .OrderBy(c => c.OrderDate)
        .ToList();
```

You can check it on https://dotnetfiddle.net/3mrZkf

Comment: That cant be.. becuse The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.. (exeption)

Comment: something? any other option..?

Comment: Do you really need to do this sum in DB? You can grab the data from db and do the sum in C#, I think it'd be easier.

Comment: i dont need this sum in db. i need this sum to display statistic about incoms to company in charts so i need to sum each data for how much getting .

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I would tell you to do hehe.

Answer (score 0):

becuse in Linq we cant groupby  `orderdate.date` so i split it. then we can order by the `date`.

```
public JsonResult TotalIncomeJson()
        {

           var tempD = db.CheckOut.Where(x => x.ISOrderComplete).ToList();
           var data = tempD.GroupBy(x => x.Order.OrderDate.Date).Select(y => new { OrderDate = y.Key, TotalPrice = y.Sum(a => a.TotalPrice) })
            .OrderBy(b=>b.OrderDate.Year).ToList();

           return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
```